# Get source from array GAPI

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api-js-client

How to get referral source from array, this is what i trying but this is not working, i don't have any error but result is 0

```
    $SITE = array('example.com','example2.shop','example3.xyz');
    $filter = 'medium==referral && source=='.$SITE.'';
    $ga->requestReportData(
        $ga_profile_id,
        array('source','date'),
        array('pageviews','visits','bounces','avgSessionDuration'),
        '-visits',
        $filter,//filter query
        $date,
        $date,
        1
    );
```

As result should be total visitors from all this sites in array

Comment: Dont you want something like `$var = $ga->requestReportData(.......)`

Comment: $results = $ga->getResults(); already added after

Comment: Ok, so show us a `var_dump($results);`

Comment: Example above just with real site name output looks like `array(0) { }`

Comment: Hmm just found in error_log `Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'GAPI: Failed to request report data. Error: "Invalid value...` looks that array does not work in this way with filters, but how to get total result than? Can't find any documentation about this.

Comment: can you remove the filter first, see if you have any rows?

Comment: Yes i have, and also have if i remove array and get only from one site stats.